# Grammar help [Antlr non LL(*)]

Tags: java, antlr

I have the below grammar for parsing expressions like these,

```
-> a
-> (a)
-> (a | b | c)
-> (a (b | (c | d)) )
-> (a (
     b (
        c x
      | d (e | f)
      )
    )
  )
```

.

```
term:   WORD term?
    |   '(' term ('|' term)* ')'
    ;


WORD    :   ('a'..'z')+ 
    ;
```

Now I tried to make a small modification to the first statement in the term rule to from `WORD term?` to `WORD term*` but antlr complains saying its non LL(*), any idea how this can be solved without resorting to global backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able modify my grammar and ended up with this which seems to work for all my cases.

```
term:   (word | options_list)+
    ;

word:   WORD
    ;

options_list:   '(' term ('|' term)* ')
    ;

WORD:   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..''Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')+
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with ANTLR 4.1:

```
term: WORD term* | '(' term ('|' term)* ')';
WORD: ('a'..'z')+;
```

What version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.x, I think Antlr 4 handles non-LL(*) and left recursion implictly.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a version issue like Stephen already supposed. LL(*) parser and state machine exist since  version 3 of ANTLR all before is just LL(k)

But why do  you want to replace term? with term* since you got term* implicietely with term? with the prior rule definition since it is already recursive.

What you create is an infinite sequence of terms with term* where each item of the sequence can  again can recursvly resolved to an infinite sewuence of terms and so on.

I think here is the reason for the ANTLR error output. I am not able to check that right now but i am pretty sure.